# Vim bundle/vundle works on OS X but not Debian Linux

Tags: debian, osx-leopard, vim

I'm using https://github.com/gmarik/vundle successfully on two Macs running 10.6.8 Snow Leopard.

However, when installing on Debian Squeeze on two machines, I get the dreaded:

> E492: Not an editor command: BundleInstall

when trying to first run vundle. I've Googled & searched all over but couldn't find anything. I suspect it's a missing dependency somewhere (I've installed moreutils) but can't quite figure it out.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the output of `tree ~/.vim` (hopefully you have tree installed).

Comment: Can you post the version of Vim on Debian and on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Vim 7.2.330 (which is the version that comes default in the repositories) on Debian Squeeze, and I'm using Vundle as well. Everything's working fine.

Make sure you have these lines in your vimrc file, like the Vundle readme says so:

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()
```

Of course you can change the Vundle path. At first I've also ran into a similar problem just because I had forgotten the parentheses in `vundle#rc()`, so make sure it looks alright.

Also, the following settings are required:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off
filetype plugin indent on
```

Again, these are all in the readme.

If this doesn't help, maybe it's better to paste your vimrc and/or give more info about your setup.

Comment: sorry for the delay but have been away. As requested, my .vimrc: